# how do i obtain multiple max values in an array simultaneously in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

how do i obtain multiple max values in an array simultaneously in matlab?
for example in a row or column of a matrix
if I have an array [45 12 56 98 67 89 23 100 201 345]
how can i get the highest values simultaneosly

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unique` which will by default sort the array in ascending order (so you'll want to `flip` it), then you can the first `N` values that you care about.

```
vals = flip(unique(data));
maxima = vals(1:N);
```

If you don't care about unique maxima, then just use `sort` instead.

```
vals = sort(data, 'descend');
maxima = vals(1:N);
```

If instead you want the maximum or minimum along a certain row/column, you can use the `dim` input to `min` or `max`.

```
% Maximum per column
maxima = max(data, [], 1);

% Maximum per row
maxima = max(data, [], 2);
```